# Json.NET and NHibernate - Deserializing a Persistent Object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, json, persistence, json.net

I'm sending a JSON collection from Javascript through a REST web service to be Deserialized using Json.NET and then finally updated in the DB using NHibernate (I'm using Fluent). The settings I'm using for Json.NET Deserialization are:

```
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });
```

My Json object is:

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "ObjectName",
  "Keys": [
    {
      "ID": 6,
      "Name": "ID"
    }
  ]
}
```

Modifying properties of the object, and even adding and modifying the child objects (Keys) and then deserializing works great. However, i can't seem to work out how to manage child object deletes. For example, if I remove a child object (using `Object.Keys.splice`), and then update, the DB record it relates to remains persistent even though the parent object which is updated does not contain them.

Additionally, I have also set 'AllDeleteOrphan' in the mapping file.

```
    // one-to-many
    HasMany(x => x.Keys)
      .Inverse()
      .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Is there any way to ensure that child objects removed via javascript will be cascade deleted when the object is deserialized and updated?

I have also read that when using NHibernate, child objects need to be removed manually from the parent collection, via `Keys.Remove(item)`, before update. It would be much more preferable (not to mention scalable) to just deserialize and update. Any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to update and then see those changes cascade, but I believe the issue has to do with the collection being marked as inverse.

Inverse=true (which is fluent nhibernate's .Inverse() is binding) is like saying "I do not manage this relationship". Due to this binding, the parent object is not deleting/updating the collection because the children manage the relationship.

Whether this makes sense or not, I could not really say without a fuller understanding of your domain.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. I tried removing that, and still have the issue with deletes. Confusing, as I always thoughts that the Inverse tag specified which side of the relationship was responsible for saving (the record), not the relationship itself?

Comment: Hold everything - removing Inverse() from the mapping had the effect of nulling the foreign key in the DB - effectively ending the relationship.. so, it worked! Just need to remove the orphans and we have a win. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you ever work out how to get it to remove the record rather than nulling the foreign key?